# I can't understand the output of this Yield expression

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code:

```
def counter(start=0):
    n = start
    while True:
        result = yield n
        print(type(result), result)
        if result == 'Q':
            break
        n += 1
c = counter()
print(next(c))
print(c.send('Wow!'))
print(next(c))
print(c.send('Q'))
```

and this is the output:

```
0
<class 'str'> Wow!
1
<class 'NoneType'> None
2
<class 'str'> Q
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gen.send.py", line 14, in <module>
print(c.send('Q')) # F
StopIteration
```

I can understand why the type line is being printed (`<classs '.....' ......>`) but I don't understand why the iteration number is being printed (0, 1 and 2) because I can't understand how the yield line is supposed to print it, can someone please explain that to me?

Comment: `print(next(c))` you're the one printing it in this statement. the value of `n` gets yielded when you call next on the generator because of `yield n`, and you print it.

Answer (score 0):

In a generator function, if you have line like:

```
result = yield n
```

there are a few simple things to keep in mind:

1. As always, when the control comes to a `yield` expression:
2. The generator will be suspended.
3. The control will go back to the "return-point" of the `next()` invocation that had last been called on the generator.
4. The value of the **yielded** expression (in this case `n`) will be returned as the return value of that `next()` invocation.
5. The effect of `send()` is to influence the value of the **entire yield expression** (not just the yielded expression), immediately after resumption of the generator. (We're talking about the post-resumption instant of time, immediately after the `send()` triggers a resumption of the generator). Here, the **yield expression** is `yield n`(and is not to be confused with the **yielded expression** `n`). By sending `'Wow'`, we are ensuring that, immediately after resumption of the suspended generator, the **yield expression** will have a string value of `'Wow'`, and it is this string value that will get assigned to `result`.

In your program, the yielded expression is always `n`, which is incremented in each iteration of the loop. This yielded expression always becomes the return value of the `next()` that had last been invoked, and this is getting printed due to `print (next(c))`.

The output of the code that you had posted, is:

```
0
<class 'str'> Wow!
1
<class 'NoneType'> None
2
<class 'str'> Q
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
```